# davfs2 (mount.davfs) alternatives that support streaming?

Tags: streaming, blocking, webdav, fuse, davfs2

`mount.davfs` (from [davfs2](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2)) allows one to mount a WebDAV server into the local filesystem. However, even if you want to read only one byte from a file, davfs2 will block until it downloads the whole file (which could be huge). For example, this blocks (virtually) forever on a WAN link.

```
dd if=/mnt/webdav/1GB.bin bs=1M count=1 of=1M.bin
```

The process can't be killed until the whole file is downloaded. (But you can force unmount, I suppose.)

In the following command, davfs2 downloads the whole file before passing a single byte to gzip:

```
pv < 100MB.bin | gzip > 100MB.bin.gz
```

I can bare with the problem in the first case (by avoiding it), but for the second case **I need the filesystem driver to pass the data to the reading process as soon as the fs driver recieves the data**, not after the whole file is downloaded. Are there any alternatives to davfs2 that can do this?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Fusedav](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/fusedav/), a WebDAV mounter for fuse. I was however not aware of such a limitation, are you sure your WebDAV server is properly configured ?